# Font is installed? function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, fonts, font-family

I can improve my function to not search by each element?

```
#Region " Font Is Installed? Function "

    ' [ Font Is Installed? Function ]
    '
    ' Examples :
    ' MsgBox(Font_Is_Installed("Lucida Console"))

    Private Function Font_Is_Installed(ByVal FontName As String) As Boolean
        Dim AllFonts As New Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection
        For Each Font As FontFamily In AllFonts.Families
            If Font.Name.ToLower = FontName.ToLower Then Return True
        Next
        Return False
    End Function

#End Region
```

> UPDATE:

Ok now I saw the ".tolist" function and now my code is like this:

```
Private Function Font_Is_Installed(ByVal FontName As String) As Boolean
    Dim AllFonts As New Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection
    Dim FontFamily As New FontFamily(FontName)
    If AllFonts.Families.ToList().Contains(FontFamily) Then Return True Else Return False
End Function
```

I have the same question: Is best improved by the second way, or I can improve it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here IS

```
    Public Shared Function IsFontInstalled(ByVal FontName As String) As Boolean
        Using TestFont As Font = New Font(FontName, 10)
            Return CBool(String.Compare(FontName, TestFont.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0)
        End Using
    End Function
```

Comment: Thankyou, but I have two little questions: first: the end using is valid after returning the value? I will mean if the "TestFont" really ends/closes after the "return"?, and second: your way don't compare each element? (sorry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: you only want to check if font is installed or not there will never be two fonts with same name,  it's ok with end using it will still clean object from memory

Answer (score 3):

```
    Dim SomeTextBox As TextBox = New TextBox()
    Dim SomeFontFamily As FontFamily = Nothing
    Dim SomeFontCollection As PrivateFontCollection = Nothing

    Try
        SomeFontFamily = New FontFamily("SomeFontFamilyName")
    Catch ex As Exception
        SomeFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection()
        SomeFontCollection.AddFontFile("SomeFontFileName")
        SomeFontFamily = SomeFontCollection.Families(0)
    End Try

    SomeTextBox.Font = New Font(SomeFontFamily, 12)
```

This way SomeFontFamily will only be created from file if it cannot be created from a local font. SomeTextBox will display the proper font.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.  Simply try to assign a font name and if it generates an error catch it and return false.

```
Private Function isFontInstalled(ByVal FontName As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim FontFamily As New FontFamily(FontName)
        FontFamily.Dispose()
        Return True
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```